# What is the cheapest train ticket between Aachen and Cologne?

Tags: trains, germany

I am going to travel with a friend from Aachen to Cologne (2 ways). 'Ive been looking at the prices and, apparently the best solution might be the regional ticket for 42€. In any case I see other options, apparently cheaper, but I am not sure I can use them.

- There is the Länder-Tickets, apparently starting at 23€ but those depend on the region
- There is also the region ticket
- Quer-durchs-Land-Ticket
- If you book in advance there are also discoutnts aparently

What are the best strategies, and ticket solutions, for a day travel (returning the same day), in a weekend, for 2 persons in between this 2 cities by train?

Comment: What other options? Why are you unsure whether you can use them? In any case, what cheap options are available on German trains depends a lot on the particular time and date you are looking for, so it will be difficult to give a general answer (that is, at the same time, extremely localized to help you and only you). Maybe you can rewrite your question to ask for good strategies for finding cheap tickets on that route?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper  Thanks. I just updated the question.

Comment: Do you return on the same day?

Comment: A slightly cheaper option may be to use a Day Ticket of the VRS regional transport authority, which should be valid for travel between Cologne and Aachen on regional trains. It costs 41 Euro for groups of up to 5 persons.

Comment: @neo yes, I will return the same day

Comment: @nsn See my updated answer, 41€ should be the cheapest option.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The prices for regional trains between Aachen and Cologne are set by the transport association VRS ([fare level 7](http://www.vrsinfo.de/fileadmin/Dateien/downloadcenter/VRS_Preistabelle_01012015_barrierefrei.pdf)).

A single trip costs 17€ per person. A four-trip ticket is available for 61.20€,
a day ticket for unlimited travel 28.50€ for one person, 41€ for five persons.

All these tickets are available last-minute at the train station.

Other alternatives would be:

- Schöner-Tag-Ticket-NRW: Valid for a day in all regional trains of North Rhine-Westphalia (including this route) for 29€ one person, 42€ five persons.
- Using inter-city trains (there aren't many). This costs 22€ per person per direction for a flexible ticket. Non-flexible tickets might be available on [reiseauskunft.bahn.de](http://reiseauskunft.bahn.de/bin/query2.exe/en) for 19€ one person or 29€ two persons (per direction) if booked early.

So in conclusion: For two persons returning on the same day a VRS fare level 7 day group ticket for 41€ is the cheapest option. The ticket is also valid for all buses and other transport in Aachen and Cologne on that day.

As this ticket is valid for five persons you might be able to find three other persons for sharing one leg of the ticket at the station.